# Cómo acceder al la session desde un servicio para obtener el usuario autenticado

Tags: javascript, nodejs, typescript

Tengo una aplicación de comercio electrónico `nodejs - express-medusajs`. Necesito capturar el usuario autenticado en la aplicación en un servico que no es llamado desde el router el cual se le puede pasar el objeto request sino es un servicio que se ejecuta cuando ocurre un evento en este caso por Redis. El servicio esta subcripto a ese evento.

Esta es mi función de autenticación:

```js
export default async (req, res) => {
  const {
    projectConfig: { jwt_secret },
  } = req.scope.resolve("configModule")
  if (!jwt_secret) {
    throw new MedusaError(
      MedusaError.Types.NOT_FOUND,
      "Please configure jwt_secret in your environment"
    )
  }
  const validated = await validator(AdminPostAuthReq, req.body)

  const authService: AuthService = req.scope.resolve("authService")
  const manager: EntityManager = req.scope.resolve("manager")
  const result = await manager.transaction(async (transactionManager) => {
    return await authService
      .withTransaction(transactionManager)
      .authenticate(validated.email, validated.password)
  })

  if (result.success && result.user) {
    // Add JWT to cookie
    req.session.jwt = jwt.sign({ userId: result.user.id }, jwt_secret, {
      expiresIn: "24h",
    })

    const cleanRes = _.omit(result.user, ["password_hash"])

    res.json({ user: cleanRes })
  } else {
    res.sendStatus(401)
  }
}
```

Necesito acceder a

> req.session.jwt

en mi servicio

```
class OrderPlacedSubscriber {
    private twilioSmsService_: TwilioSmsService;
    private orderService_: OrderService;
    private emailService_: EmailService;
    private orderPriceService_: OrderPriceService;
    private productService_: ProductService;

    constructor({
                    twilioSmsService,
                    orderService,
                    emailService,
                    orderPriceService,
                    eventBusService,
                    productService
                }) {
        this.twilioSmsService_ = twilioSmsService
        this.orderService_ = orderService
        this.emailService_ = emailService
        this.orderPriceService_ = orderPriceService
        this.productService_ = productService
.....
    }
}
```

Donde mi servicio **OrderPlacedSubscriber** no se ejecuta desde una api sino desde un evento de **Redis**

Comment: y que has intentado???

Comment: aun nada, no se como acceder al req desde una funcion externa aun router

Comment: Siempre recurrir a [es.so] debe ser tu último recurso. Muestra lo que has intentado, y el problema _específico_ que has tenido. De nuevo: primero debes intentar algo.

Comment: bueno @RichardUrquizaSantiesteban primero tienes que intentar investigas y hacer tu propio codigo y si tienes problemas entonces nos dice que problema precisamente tienes para que podamos ayudarte, decir como se hacen XYZ cosas no es un topic del sitio...

Comment: sin codigo no hay nada que hacer, intenta buscar algun tutorial de logueo y despues postea algo de codigo, si aun tienes dudas

Comment: Profundizando la búsqueda en la documentación de medusajs encontré la respuesta a lo que quería hacer:
https://docs.medusajs.com/development/endpoints/example-logged-in-user

Answer (score -1, accepted):

En la documentación del sitio oficial de **medusajs** en la sección [docs.medusajs.com/development/endpoints/example-logged-in-user](https://docs.medusajs.com/development/endpoints/example-logged-in-user) aborda y pone ejemplo de como inyectar al núcleo de **medusa** el user logeado para luego acceder a este en cualquier parte de la app.

```
import { User, UserService } from "@medusajs/medusa"

export async function registerLoggedInUser(req, res, next) {
  let loggedInUser: User | null = null

  if (req.user && req.user.userId) {
    const userService = 
      req.scope.resolve("userService") as UserService
    loggedInUser = await userService.retrieve(req.user.userId)
  }

  req.scope.register({
    loggedInUser: {
      resolve: () => loggedInUser,
     },
   })
  
  next()
}
```

Comment: Aunque teoricamente este enlace conteste la pregunta, es preferible que incluyas las partes esenciales del mismo en la respuesta. Los enlaces pueden caducar y desaparecer. Ademas llevar al usuario a que lea en otro lugar la respuesta, no es la mejor opción.